# cronファイルに、長いコマンドを複数行にまたがって書きたい。

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Ubuntuで、長いコマンドをスケジュール実行させています。
見にくいので改行を入れたいのですが、どのように記述すればよいでしょうか？

以下のように、\区切りで改行を入れたら、正しく動作しませんでした。

```
#SHELL=/bin/bash
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

*/1 * * * * root echo `date` >> /home/sasaki/test1.txt; \
echo `date` >> /home/sasaki/test2.txt;
```

Ubuntuのバージョンは、
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

本家Stack OverflowやUnix & Linux StackExchangeにほとんど同じ趣旨の質問があるようです。

- [linux - Crontab Command Separate Line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661492/)
- [How come I can't use `\` to continue a line in crontab? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605842/)

結論から言うと、crontabに長いコマンドを複数行にわたって記述する方法は存在しないようです。Manページにはっきり書かれているので仕方がありませんね。日本語版でも同じ記述が見つかります：

> シェルの行末の "\" のような、 コマンドの単一の行を複数行に分割して記述する方法は、crontab にはない。
> （https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/ja/man5/crontab.5.html）

したがって、y_waiwaiさんのおっしゃるように外部のシェルスクリプトファイルに書き出してそれを実行するようにするしかなさそうです。

Answer (score 1):

普通はその長いコマンド列をシェルスクリプトにして、それで実行させますね

Comment: ありがとうございます。
改行する方法ないこと、他にシェルスクリプトを用意して実行させる方法があること、理解できました。